# Retrieving text from a tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a loop that retrieves the values from the database and puts it into a unordered list. What I want to do is to retrieve the value of the title within the same list element.

By saying this I mean, I want to get "This is a title" when I click the first link and get "This is title number two" when clicking the second link and so on. I tried using `$(this).parent().text()` but it returns "undefined"...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3 class="title">This is a title number two</h3>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
    <li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="title">This is a title</h3>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Here's the full script:

```html
<?php

require_once('db.php');
$sql = "SELECT id, name, user, done, created FROM todos";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Todo App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function checkDelete(event){

      var item_name = $('#title').text();
      var answer = confirm("Delete " + item_name + "?");
      if(!answer){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="items">
        <h2>Your todo list</h2>
        <ul>
          <?php


          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

              // output data of each row
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  echo '<li>' . '<p id="title">' . $row['name']. '</p>' .'<a href=delete.php?id='. $row['id'] .' onClick=checkDelete(event)>Delete</a>';
                  echo '<a class="update" href=todo.php?id='.$row['id'].'&name=' . urlencode($row['name']) .'>Update</a></li>';

              }
          } else {
              echo "0 results";
          }
          $conn->close();



          ?>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <form id="todo" action="addtodo.php" method="post">
      <label for="item">Add</label>
      <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
$(this).parent().text()
```

won't work because `$(this).parent()` is going to select the `<li>` element, which doesn't have any value set for `.text()`

Select the a tag and set an on click event listener and get the previous element's value

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var title = $(this).prev().text();   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.title').on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).siblings('h3').html());
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>This is a title number two</h3>
        <a class="title" href="#">Delete</a>
    <li>
    <li>
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <a class="title" href="#">Delete</a>
    <li>
</ul>
```